# How to output link to gitlab job for Fastlane Scan Results in Slack

Tags: gitlab, slack-api, fastlane, gitlab-api, fastlane-scan

Is there a way to create a link to the gitlab job that ran when outputting the result of a Fastlane Scan to Slack?

[image]

[image]

I want to have a link from within the Slack results to the gitlab job that ran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by adding the following to our gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
script:
    - export JOB_ID=$CI_JOB_ID
```

And then in our fastlane file, I adjusted the slack_message field within the scan section:

```
slack_message: "CI Job: https://<urltogitlab>/" +  ENV['JOB_ID'],
```

Answer (score 1):

The `slack_message` argument supports [Slack Flavoured Markdown](https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting#linking-urls), so you can pass a URL to it and it will link in Slack. So for example

```
slack_message: "QA UI Tests on iPhone 13 Pro"
```

should change to

```
slack_message: "<https://gitlab.com/link-to-job-that-you-provide|QA UI Tests on iPhone 13 Pro>"
```

And then that text will become a link to the job.